# Making a new copy with only values - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write a code that will make copy of two sheets into new workbook. However, I receve error message and the values do not show..

```
    Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
    Dim newName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

    If newName <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    End If
    End Sub

    Sub SaveSheets()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim myFile
    Dim myCount
    Dim actSheet
    Dim i
    Dim WsTabelle As Worksheet

    'mypath = InputBox("Enter the path", "Save to...", "C:\temp")
    mypath = "C:\temp"
    ChDrive mypath
    ChDir mypath

    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell").Select
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell").Copy Before:=Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell")
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell").Select
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell (2)").Name = "Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
         "C:\temp\Bearbeitungsstatus.xlsm" _
         , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    ' Löschen überflüssiger Sheets
    For Each WsTabelle In Sheets
        With WsTabelle
            ' Dein Makro, Cells und Range mit Punkt
            actSheet = .Name
            If .Name = "Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx" Then
              ' mache nichts
              actSheet = .Name
            ElseIf .Name = "Übersicht AP-Verbrauch" Then
              ' mache nichts
              actSheet = .Name
            Else
              WsTabelle.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next WsTabelle

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
         " C:\temp \Bearbeitungsstatus.xlsm" _
         , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False


    End Sub
Public Sub SubstitudeFieldValues()
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx").Select
    ' Find the last row of data
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    FinalCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Loop through each row
   For Col = 1 To FinalCol
        colTitle = Cells(1, Col).Value
        If colTitle = "K1" Or _
           colTitle = "K2" Or _
           colTitle = "K3" Or _
           colTitle = "S1" Or _
           colTitle = "S2" Or _
           colTitle = "S3" Or _
           colTitle = "P1" Or _
           colTitle = "P2" Or _
           colTitle = "P3" Or _
           colTitle = "T1" Or _
           colTitle = "T2" Or _
           colTitle = "T3" Or _
           colTitle = "A1" Or _
           colTitle = "A2" Or _
           colTitle = "D1" Or _
           colTitle = "D2" Then

            For x = 2 To FinalRow
                wert = Cells(x, Col)
                If wert <> Leer Then
                    'Range(Cells(x, Col), Cells(x, Col)).Select
                    Cells(x, Col).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                        :=False, Transpose:=False
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next Col
End Sub
```

The original task is to make copy of two sheets in the new workbook. 
Making a copy of "**Fertigstellungsgrad**" with ability of rename (It should be called "Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx" - Date.Month.Year) and the copy should contain only values. "**Übersicht AP-Verbrauch**"(this one should stay the same, without any changes)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soxq7.png

Kind regards, Mario

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please can you edit your question to include the error message you receive and also identify where in the code the error occurs.  This should make it much easier (and faster) for you to get a resolution.

Comment: Could just be how the data was copied but there is whitespace in one of your paths that will be problematic: " C:\temp \Bearbeitungsstatus.xlsm".  Leading whitespace and whitespace after 'temp '.

Comment: Error is "1004" - Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Which line of code is it failing on?

Comment: "Sub SaveSheets()" and "Public Sub SubstitudeFieldValues()"

Comment: Looks like the spaces in your filename.  in Sub SaveSheets() there is a space between the " C:\  I removed it from your code which allowed the file to save.

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces in the filenames in `Sub SaveSheets()`

I changed:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
     " C:\temp \Bearbeitungsstatus.xlsm" _
     , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
     "C:\temp\Bearbeitungsstatus.xlsm" _
     , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

and I could save the file.

I modified the code below from an IF / FOR to a CASE SELECT and modified the range for `FinalRow` variable to be the current column used range.  It looks like your For / Next statement in the sub  is pseudo code so I haven't made any changes to it.

```
Public Sub SubstitudeFieldValues()
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx").Select
    ' Find the last row of data
    'FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    FinalCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Loop through each row

    For Col = 1 To FinalCol

        colTitle = Cells(1, Col).Value

    Select Case colTitle
    Case "K1", "K2", "K3", "S1", "S2", "S3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "A1", "A2", "D1", "D2"
        FinalRow = Range(colTitle).End(xlDown).Row
    Case else
        goto NotFound
    End Select

            For x = 2 To FinalRow
                wert = Cells(x, Col)
                If wert <> Leer Then
                    'Range(Cells(x, Col), Cells(x, Col)).Select
                    Cells(x, Col).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                        :=False, Transpose:=False
                End If
            Next x

NotFound:
    Next Col
End Sub
```

To set the name of the new sheet to include the date, you can change your code in SaveSheets() from:

```
Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell (2)").Name = "Fertigstellungsgrad xx.xx.xx"
```

to

```
Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad aktuell (2)").Name = "Fertigstellungsgrad " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yy")
```

Your subsequent Select statement in `Sub SubstitudeFieldValues()` would become:

```
Public Sub SubstitudeFieldValues()
    Sheets("Fertigstellungsgrad " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yy").Select
```